# Scala type level programming - representing a hierarchy

Tags: scala, type-level-computation

I'm learning about type level programming in Scala and I'm curious if it's possible to represent a tree or hierarchy using type level programming.

The simple case would be a multi-level tree

```
A_
  |
  B_
    |C
    |D
  |     
  E
```

How would one represent such a structure?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your question, ya, trees are possible. Compared to a language like Haskell though, I found that I had to jump through more hoops.

Comment: Great! How would I do it..? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27488849/3000206 This is a question of mine when I first picked up Scala. The answer I chose works, but like I said, it's far more complicated than in other languages.

Comment: You might want to check out Scalaz's Tree...here's an example: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tree.html

Comment: Yeah I like Scalaz tree but its value not type level

Comment: You could write this as something like `type Tree[A, B, C, D, E] = (A, (B, C :: D :: HNil) :: E :: HNil)` with Shapeless's `HList` (or something similar with tuples), and then follow Shapeless's `ops` patterns to implement a `Size` type class, etc. If you're interested in a Shapeless solution I'd be happy to post something later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can represent a heterogeneous tree in Scala, with one of the simplest being something like this:

```
type MyTreeShape[A, B, C, D, E] = (A, (B, (C, D), E))
```

This has some limitations, though (like the fact that you can't have a tuple as the value of a leaf, since we're using tuple-ness in our representation). For the rest of this answer I'll be using a slightly more complex representation involving [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s `HList`:

```
import shapeless._

type MyTreeShape[A, B, C, D, E] =
  A ::
    (B ::
      (C :: HNil) ::
      (D :: HNil) ::
      HNil) ::
    (E :: HNil) ::
    HNil
```

Here a tree is an `HList` whose head is the value and whose tail is an `HList` of child trees.

If we want to do anything usefully generic with these kinds of trees, we'll need some type classes. I'll write up a quick depth-first `FlattenTree` on the model of the type classes in Shapeless's `ops.hlist` package as an example. Other type classes for size, depth, etc. can be implemented similarly.

Here's the type class and a convenience method that'll make it easy to use:

```
trait FlattenTree[T <: HList] extends DepFn1[T] { type Out <: HList }

def flattenTree[T <: HList](t: T)(implicit f: FlattenTree[T]): f.Out = f(t)
```

Now for instances, which we'll put in the companion object:

```
object FlattenTree {
  type Aux[T <: HList, Out0 <: HList] = FlattenTree[T] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def flattenTree[H, T <: HList](implicit
    tf: FlattenForest[T]
  ): Aux[H :: T, H :: tf.Out] = new FlattenTree[H :: T] {
    type Out = H :: tf.Out

    def apply(t: H :: T): H :: tf.Out = t.head :: tf(t.tail)
  }
}
```

Note that this needs a helper type class, `FlattenForest`:

```
trait FlattenForest[F <: HList] extends DepFn1[F] { type Out <: HList }

object FlattenForest {
  type Aux[F <: HList, Out0 <: HList] = FlattenForest[F] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit val hnilFlattenForest: Aux[HNil, HNil] = new FlattenForest[HNil] {
    type Out = HNil

    def apply(f: HNil): HNil = HNil
  }

  implicit def hconsFlattenForest[
    H <: HList,
    OutH <: HList,
    T <: HList,
    OutT <: HList
  ](implicit
    hf: FlattenTree.Aux[H, OutH],
    tf: Aux[T, OutT],
    pp: ops.hlist.Prepend[OutH, OutT]
  ): Aux[H :: T, pp.Out] = new FlattenForest[H :: T] {
    type Out = pp.Out

    def apply(f: H :: T): pp.Out = pp(hf(f.head), tf(f.tail))
  }
}
```

Now we can use it like this:

```
val myTree: MyTreeShape[String, Int, Char, Symbol, Double] =
  "foo" :: (10 :: HList('a') :: HList('z) :: HNil) :: HList(0.0) :: HNil

val flattened = flattenTree(myTree)
```

And let's show the static type is appropriate:

```
flattened: String :: Int :: Char :: Symbol :: Double :: HNil
```

And that's exactly what we want.

You could do all this without Shapeless, but it would involve an incredible amount of boilerplate.